# Lawnmower locked up, cannot turn shaft

Tags: engine, oil, small-engine, lawnmower, seized-engine

[image: top view of engine] Thank you for coming here. My dad  recently picked up a Craftsman gcv 160 mower. When I unloaded it, I ran it for a while, then drained the oil. Remember, it worked when I got it. The oil was very grey in color. I put in New oil, which was a mixture of sae-30 and hd-30. I used it to cut some grass for about 20 minutes, using a sock as an air filter as it had no filter. It seems to only run when choked, but it still ran good overall. The next day, I sprayed carbeurator cleaner into it and tried to start it. This was when it locked up. These are the things I tried:

- I tried forcefully turning it, which did not work.
- I removed the spark plug, fearing it may be hydro-locked.
- I drained the oil again, it was very grey also.
- I sprayed pb-blaster in the spark plug hole, with it tipped back at almost a right angle. The cylinder was about half-filled with it.

I perdiodically checked it as I let it sit overnight, adding more penetrating fluid as it evaporated. After this didn't work, I gave up and decided to go here after a couple of days of giving up and working on other mowers. Please ask me anything that could help any of us solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the engine is toast.

Comment: It must be fixable, right?

Comment: Anything can be fixed but you may spend more doing so than buying a new one. This is probably why someone chucked it out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From what you are saying, the main engine shaft does not turn at all? Have you tried it forward and backward (should be able to turn it by the blade by hand ... *being careful*, of course!).

Comment: Yes, I tried that.